# jquery adding attribute in the element tr, td and div

Tags: jquery

Sir,
I need to use jquery to add element in tag `td`, `tr` and `div` which contains `onmouseout` and `onmouseover`.

If found `onmouseout="ANY FUNCTION"` then i need to add attribute `onblur="SAME FUNCTION AS onmouseout"`.

Then if found `onmouseover="Any Function"` then i need to add attribute `onfocus="sane functions as onmouseover"`.

This functions contains in tag `td, tr or div`.

**Example td:**

```
<td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" id="zz1_GS">
```

**Then i need:**

```
<td onmouseover="Menu_A(this)" onfocus="Menu_A(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhvr(this)" onblur="Menu_Unhvr(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" id="zz1_GS">
```

**Example tr:**

```
<tr onmouseover="Menu_HoverDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(this)" id="zz86756f">
```

**Then i need something like this:**

```
<tr onmouseover="MDynamic(this)" onfocus="MDynamic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_r(this)" onblur="Menu_r(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Ky(this)" id="zz86756f">
```

**Example div:**

```
<div class="1_5656" id="d867444f" onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
```

**Then i need something like this:**

```
<div class="1_5656" id="d867444f" onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onfocus="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)" onblur="PopOStop(this)" style="text-align:center;">
```

The id name is not same and the level of td and tr is not uniform.

Can anyone help me to achive this?

I have done this code but its not working:

```
            $('div[onmouseout]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onblur', $(this).attr('onmouseout'));
        }

        $('div[onmouseover]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onfocus', $(this).attr('onmouseover'));
        }

        $('tr[onmouseout]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onblur', $(this).attr('onmouseout'));
        }

        $('tr[onmouseover]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onfocus', $(this).attr('onmouseover'));
        }

        $('td[onmouseout]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onblur', $(this).attr('onmouseout'));
        }

        $('td[onmouseover]').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onfocus', $(this).attr('onmouseover'));
        }
```

Comment: Confusing question ,cant u elaborate :(

Comment: Please don't use `onwhatever` attributes to trigger JavaScript. It's easier, in the long run, to add the handlers using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: Mani: the only thing i see is that you need a different function for mouseover and mouseout events ? is that what u need ?

Comment: If you haven't tried anything than try and if you cannot reach your goal that ask here with some samples of your work. This is not a place where people write code instead of you

Comment: Basically you need to find all tr, td and div and that iterate through all results and check if $(this) have onmouseout attribute that add onblur attribute with value of onmouseout and etc.

Comment: i already done javascript function for mouseover event and mouseout event but i need to add another attribute in same tag. Because some browser not support mouseover but support onfocus and some browser not support mouseout but support onblur, i need to add onblur and onfocus event in the same tag of mouseover and mouseover

Comment: That can help you http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ http://api.jquery.com/each/ http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: This is what i done but its not working

Comment: Did you placed your jquery code in $(function () { //here? });

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible to do this just by copying the attributes, and using an empty attribute selector to grab all elements with that particular attribute:

```
var $mo = $('[onmouseover]'),
    fstr = $mo.attr('onmouseover'),
    bstr = $mo.attr('onmouseout');
$mo.attr('onfocus',fstr).attr('onblur',bstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("div, tr, td").not("[onmouseout='']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('onblur', $(this).attr('onmouseout'));
});

$("div, tr, td").not("[onmouseover='']").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('onfocus', $(this).attr('onmouseover'));
});
```

**Update.**
That works fine just checked. Recheck with my code to find out where you fail:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script>
 function PopOUp() {}
 function PopOStop() {}

 $(function () {
    $("div, tr, td").not("[onmouseout='']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('onblur', $(this).attr('onmouseout'));
    });

    $("div, tr, td").not("[onmouseover='']").each(function () {
        $(this).attr('onfocus', $(this).attr('onmouseover'));
    });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="1_5656" id="d867444f" onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)" style="text-align:center;"></div>

<table onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)">
    <tr onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)">
        <td onmouseover="PopOUp(this)" onmouseout="PopOStop(this)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to copy paste your code in html file and run it. After i view source code its not added onblur or onfocus element in the div,table,tr and td also

Comment: You do something completely wrong. Did you have an internet connection when you trying to do this?(jquery from this example downloaded from web). http://jsfiddle.net/fQTVX/ Check this here is same example in result window here is div, tr and td elements with onblur and onfocus. Also do you have any errors in console while running this script?

Comment: I tested, actually i try to put the alert script alert($(this).attr('onblur')) its working but when i view source code the attribute onfocus and onblur is not added in div or td or tr element.